# Duplication assignment to the 'Content' property of the 'NavigationView' object

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, uwp

```
<Page
x:Class="HamburgerExample2.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:HamburgerExample2"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:appmodel="using:Windows.ApplicationModel"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<NavigationView x:Name="NavView" SelectionChanged="NavView_SelectionChanged" Header="Welcome">
    <NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <NavigationViewItem Icon="Home" Content="Home" Tag="Home"/>
        <NavigationViewItem Icon="Share" Content="Share" Tag="Share"/>
    </NavigationView.MenuItems>

    <Frame x:Name="ContentFrame" Navigated="ContentFrame_Navigated">
        <Frame.ContentTransitions>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <NavigationThemeTransition/>
            </TransitionCollection>
        </Frame.ContentTransitions>

    </Frame>

    <Grid></Grid>

</NavigationView>
```

In Visual Studio 2017 I get an error. Duplication assignment to the 'Content' property of the 'NavigationView' object. How can I add a Grid to the right of the hamburger menu?

Comment: Where do you want the Grid in relation to the Frame?

Answer (score 0):

The `Content` of [`NavagationView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/navigationview) can not be set more than once. I'm not sure why you need to put the `Grid` together with `Frame` here, but if you do want this layout you could add a parent panel for `Grid` and `Frame`. For example:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Frame x:Name="ContentFrame" Margin="24">
        <Frame.ContentTransitions>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <NavigationThemeTransition />
            </TransitionCollection>
        </Frame.ContentTransitions>
    </Frame>
    <Grid Width="200" Height="200">
        <Button
            Width="150"
            Height="50"
            Content="test" />
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```